# Returning max value based on two conditions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup, google-sheets-dates

I've been reading through a lot of other solutions to similar problems but am not able to resolve my issues.

I have a Google Sheet with two sheets I am working with:

**Sheet 1**

A list of contacts (last name, first name, position, etc.) with column 18 (R) being a "last contact type" (phone call, meeting, etc. drop-down list, data validation) and column 19 (S) being a " last contacted date" column (data validation, date).

**Sheet 2**

A list of weekly interactions (last name, first name, position, etc.) with column 6 (F) being a "date" (data validation, date) column.

**What I want to do**

I need to build a formula for Sheet 1, column 19 (S), that returns the max date value from Sheet 2 in column 6 (F) IF Sheet 1 column 18 (R) is not null (I used `">0"`) AND Sheet 1 Column 1 (A, Last Name) equals Sheet 2, Column 1 (A, Last Name).

This would allow me to track when the last time I talked with my clients by keeping a weekly log of interactions.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output pls

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VvF5uR2CG9qeXSTPLuYcgTU6bElIZCHvQZakRgOasy0/edit?usp=sharing

Here is a copy of the sheet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3:A, SORT(Interactions!A5:F, 6, 0), 6, 0)))
```

[image: 0]